# How to access text boxes on a particular slide and change its text in Google Slides?

Tags: javascript, google-slides

I am trying to access a text box on Google slides in order to change its text but every time I run the programme, it prints "textRange" on the alert box despite the fact that there's some text in the text box.

```
function updateTextBox() {
  var slides = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSlides();
  var shapes = slides[0].getShapes();
  var text = shapes[0].getText();
  SlidesApp.getUi().alert(text);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You are missing `asString()`

Indeed,it is documented that the method [getText()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/shape#gettext) return a [TextRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/text-range).

`TextRange` is a class that has methods, to return the actual test fo the range you need to use the method [asString()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/text-range#asString()).

`var text = shapes[0].getText().asString();`

[image]